# Represent a matrix of strings by their index in another array

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix

I would like to represent the strings in `edges` by their index in `nodes` using numpy.

```
nodes = np.array('A B C D E'.split())
edges = np.array([['A', 'B'],
                  ['A', 'C'],
                  ['B', 'C'],
                  ['B', 'E'],
                  ['D', 'E']])
```

**Desired Output**

```
np.array([[0, 1],
          [0, 2],
          [1, 2],
          [1, 4],
          [3, 4]])
```

Obvious non-optimized way is to create a `dict` and replace the string with the value of the `dict`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
np.searchsorted(nodes,edges)
```

Sample run -

```
In [17]: nodes
Out[17]: 
array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 
      dtype='|S1')

In [18]: edges
Out[18]: 
array([['A', 'B'],
       ['A', 'C'],
       ['B', 'C'],
       ['B', 'E'],
       ['D', 'E']], 
      dtype='|S1')

In [19]: np.searchsorted(nodes,edges)
Out[19]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 4],
       [3, 4]])
```

If `nodes` is not sorted, we need to use `sorter` argument with it, as shown in the modified version of sample run -

```
In [44]: nodes
Out[44]: 
array(['E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'], 
      dtype='|S1')

In [45]: edges
Out[45]: 
array([['A', 'B'],
       ['A', 'C'],
       ['B', 'C'],
       ['B', 'E'],
       ['D', 'E']], 
      dtype='|S1')

In [46]: sidx = nodes.argsort()

In [47]: sidx[np.searchsorted(nodes,edges,sorter=sidx)]
Out[47]: 
array([[4, 3],
       [4, 2],
       [3, 2],
       [3, 0],
       [1, 0]])
```